# Why was my suggested edit rejected in particular?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

Randomly I look if I got a rejected suggestion and I found [one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/586321) from these days. But I really don't get it.
My POV in this case is that I took question-comments from others and their answer-comment from OP. And that I did not include any answer to the question itself.

There are more like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/586368) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/580095). The rejection in these cases came from a user with higher rep and an the approval from a lower rep one, so I assume he/ she knows why and what. But I don't understand the (stock) phrase. And in lack of a private chat system I can't ask him/her directly.

I know that only the rejecters know why they rejected, but I hope other users still can enlighten me because I don't like to annoy the review system. So my question is: *Where in particular did I edit wrong?*

Comment: Tips: try to get the OP to edit the post rather than doing it yourself - it makes the person aware of the feature. And don't add tags if you're not sure they belong. Put "maybe this needs tags [such] [and such]"  in the edit comment instead. AFAIK the edit is fine, but you're asking "a lot of work" from the reviewers (check out the question, review the edit wrt posted comments, think about the tags.)

Comment: This actually came up in my queue - and I actually passed on it as *Not Sure*. While it seems fairly legit, it does make a lot of changes to the original question. In my case, unless I am totally certain one way or another, I just ask for the next edit. Perhaps as I get more familiar and confident with editing I will approve these, but I would love to see how many people passed on that one in particular.

Comment: You could probably add "moved OP comments into the question" to make it clearer; these kind of edits sometimes take me by surprise, so having a more explicit edit description helps a lot.

Comment: Do me a favor... ***do not edit code in questions***. Also, the "Edit:" notation should be dropped.

Comment: One option is to earn enough rep that your edits are no longer suggestions and don't require approval.

Comment: Okay, I will drop the "Edit:" and yes, code editing is bad, the missing "{": I yielded to temptation. Yes, I ask about a lot of work to see if I included the right comments because it took me same work to get it in. So I will state it more clear in the long conclusion line.

Comment: I wouldn't have approved the last one btw; where did `<!-- language-all: lang-php -->` come from?

Comment: @Jack This comes from the Question. And usually the highlighting appears from question tags and there are no concurring ones in this case. But in preview this is not all time visible. And only 6 blanks are not valid.

Comment: in copying-comments suggestions, I would use a horizontal separator `---` instead of "Edit from comments:" and I'd comment like "clarification copied into question from OP comments". Other than that, these look pretty good

Comment: @Mat You are right, I have to try it for every case again. I usually refuse to do if the OP was offline since more than a month.

Comment: I agree with Bobby - changing code is reason enough to reject an edit. Code of answer might be improved to certain level as long as not radically changing it, but code in the question itself is many times the source of the problem so fixing it pretty much turns the whole question pointless. Indentation is the only thing that should be fixed in those cases.

Comment: By the way, adding comments into the post it valid in my opinion, especially in old questions where the chance of the OP to get back and do it himself is very low. On the other hand, I tend to reject minor format fixes on old questions (over a year in the past) as it's not reason enough to bump the question back to the front page so I would also have rejected [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/review-beta/suggested-edits/580095) probably adding reason "post too old to matter".

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Thanks for the hint to find a line to balance between "too old to matter" and "too messy for a Q&A site".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To me the edits look reasonably legit and I would probably have approved them.

You may want to try and get the OP to edit their question first though. Leave a comment, favourite the question for later review, and teach the OP how to fish instead of handing one to them.

Not everyone reviewing is paying enough attention to see that you moved comments from the OP into the question. The review system is not infallible, and with only two reviews per pending edit there is plenty of scope for 2 people to misunderstand. I wouldn't trust their rep count in that regard either. :-)

You've made over 300 suggested edits, which only increased your chances to get a few misfire reviews. I wouldn't worry too much about these particular rejections.

Comment: Thanks for encouraging, but would you suggest that I re-edit the questions again in this case? And yes, I agree that 2 or 3 reviewers are not the community at all.

Comment: Yes, I'd say the edit is legitimate enough. Personally, I'd even leave out the 'Edit:' header, perhaps.

Answer (score 5):

Changing code in a question, when the asker says "This doesn't work", is really dangerous. You might accidentally fix the problem.

Changing brace placement is an ever bigger no-no. This is a semi-religious matter, where moving the opening brace from the end of one line to the beginning of the next, or vice versa, is about the worst thing you can do to a programmer. The code gets totally ugly!

That alone can be reason to reject an edit (if you do it the wrong way :-).

Comment: I agree to that religious matter of brace placement. I did not look all my reviews back, but I usually (with exceptions) move braces to a new line. _Code:_ I definitly agree to change no character. In _this case_ there was an opening "{" missing but concerning the comments this was _not_ part of problem. It totally looked like "ooops lost in c'n'p" Otherwise the method would have thrown more and different errors than claimed. That is why I yielded to temptation _this time_. But I will keep brace placement in mind.